# Doubts about Chisel dontTouch API and FIRRTL optimiztion

Tags: scala, chisel

There are some doubts when I learn Chisel currently.

It seems FIRRTL would do some optimization to generate out verilog code.

And I write an example, and going to run it.

But I find some issues.

My example code( I just take it for experiment so it may being odd):

```
class Example extends Module {
  val io  = IO(new Bundle {
    val in  = Input(UInt(16.W))
  })

  val x = RegInit(0.U(16.W))
  val y = RegInit(0.U(16.W)) 

  x := io.in
  y := x    

}
```

After generating fir file, I run FIRRTL compiler to see whether it incurrs Dead Code Eliminataion.

```
======== Starting Transform DeadCodeElimination ========
[DCE] reg Example.x
[DCE] reg Example.y
```

I find out it can be solved by using dontTouch API:

```
  class Example extends Module {
    val io  = IO(new Bundle {
      val in  = Input(UInt(16.W))
    })

    val x = RegInit(0.U(16.W))
    val y = RegInit(0.U(16.W)) 

    x := io.in
    dontTouch(x)
    y := x    

}
```

I check out with the same flow above. It still gets same result:

```
======== Starting Transform DeadCodeElimination ========
[DCE] reg Example.x
[DCE] reg Example.y
```

Questions:

(1) Do I misunderstand dontTouch API or I use it in wrong way?

(2) x value would change with io.in signal, why x is treat as unusing part then compiler regards it as dead code?

Answer (score 1):

I think your expectations here are correct.
I believe this is a version/release problem. When I run your code I see

```
======== Starting Transform DeadCodeElimination ========
[DCE] reg DontTouch.y
--------------------------------------------------------
```

There's been a lot of work on DontTouch lately. I will dig a little deeper and see if I can figure out where this has been fixed.

Comment: It looks like this was fixed in PR #735 in https://github.com/freechipsproject/firrtl/pull/735